# Instead of add category name category id should added in to the database using JComboBox java netbeans

Tags: java, database, swing, jcombobox

Instead of add category name category id should added in to the database table. I am creating simple sales project. When loaded the `JComboBox` category name should be displayed select the item from the combo box and add into the database Instead of add category name add category id in to the database. Loading the records from the table creating the `CategoryItem` class object:

```
jComboBox1.addItem(CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));
```

I couldn't load the data. I attached code step by step below.

**I created the class `CategoryItem`**

```
class CategoryItem
{
    int id;
    String name;

    // add other fields if you want...

    CategoryItem(int id, String name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
 public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Loading the records from the table  creating the `CategoryItem` class object:

```
jComboBox1.addItem(CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));
```

At this line, I couldn't load the data.

```
public void LoadCategory()
{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javapos","root","");
            insert = con1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM category");
             ResultSet rs = insert.executeQuery();
             jComboBox1.removeAllItems();

             while(rs.next())
             {
                 jComboBox1.addItem(CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));               
             }        
             } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            }
}
```

This is code to be insert the record in to the table.

```
String name =txtproduct.getText();
            String dec =txtdec.getText();

           CategoryItem item = (CategoryItem)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/javapos","root","");
            insert = con1.prepareStatement("insert into product (productname,description,category)values(?,?,?)");
            insert.setString(1,name);
            insert.setString(2,dec);
             insert.setInt(3,item.id);
            insert.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sucsessfully Saved");
```

Comment: "at this line.i couldn't load the data." what do you mean? in your method `LoadCategory()` you have omitted the exception, print the exception and
 see whether there is an exception `catch( SQLException e ) { e.printStackTrace() }` that my help you

Comment: sir i called the object inside Jcombobox it show error in red line CategoryItem jComboBox1.addItem(CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2))); is there any wrong on this line

Comment: If that is the case what does that red line says as the error? is `CategoryItem` in the same package where  `LoadCategory()` is? if not you have to make `CategoryItem` as `public class CategoryItem` and `CategoryItem(int id, String name)` into `public CategoryItem(int id, String name)`

Comment: cannot find the symbol  method CategoryItem(int,String) this the error displayed at the red line i made  it as public but error not go away .

Comment: `jComboBox1.addItem(new CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2))); ` silly me didnt see that before. this should correct you problem

Comment: jComboBox1.addItem(new CategoryItem(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2))); i tried this way also sir. still error displayed .

Comment: i couldn't load the category

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186761/discussion-between-dush-and-james-jim).

Comment: Did you see the error? sir

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. But most importantly..

Comment: 4) `catch (Exception e) {
            }` **Don't ignore exceptions!** They inform us exactly what went wrong. Unless logging is implemented, at least call `Throwable.printStackTrace()`

Comment: thanks sir it is working great.

Comment: *"thanks sir"* Who are you replying to? What is working great? Tip: Add @Dush (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.